# Directions and Map default floating button not showing

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to override the OnMarkerClickListener but the problem is something changed. By default, once a marker is clicked, the directions and map floating button are shown right at the bottom of the map fragment.

After I override the OnMarkerClickListener it changed. Once the marker is clicked it no longer shows the directions and map buttons.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if(previousMarkerClicked == null) {
        previousMarkerClicked = marker;
    }else{
        previousMarkerClicked.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
        previousMarkerClicked = marker;
    }
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    marker.hideInfoWindow();
    markerInfoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    selectedMarker_index = getMarkerIndex(marker.getTitle());
    return true;
}
```

How can I show the directions and map button in my map fragment?

[Picture that shows Buttons are shown once the marker is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/598Rw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google docs give this information on how to set the return value of the `onMarkerClick()` method:

> true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default
>   behavior should not occur); false otherwise (i.e., the default
>   behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera to move
>   to the marker and an info window to appear.

Basically, this means if you return `true` (as you are doing) the developer is saying "let me take care of everything". Returning `false` means that in addition to what the developer instructs inside the method, the system will also do what it usually does.

So if you want the Google Maps Toolbar to appear, you need to return `false` in the `onMarkerClick()` method.

---

**NOTE:** 

You if for some reason you wish to return `false` in the `onMarkerClick()` method, but do not want to display the Toolbar you can add this:

```
mMap.getUISettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: thank you for that, I have been thinking how to achieve both(hiding the info while not consuming the event by returning false.